# Convert MongoDB Find() return information to String with PyMongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to connect to my Twitter application by fetching the consumer key and access token from a MongoDatabase. I'm relatively new to MongoDB and am still trying to get a handle on things. I need the data as a string, but it's being returned as a cursor. I understand that what I have so far won't be the exact value im looking for, but rather something like

```
{"value" : "ggggktjjjfr4kf0k04kf0rkforvo"}
```

but if I could at least get this as a string I could begin to decode it. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
consumer_key = collection_Authentication.find({"name":"consumer_key"}, {"_id":0, "value":1})
consumer_secret=collection_Authentication.find({"name":"consumer_secret"}, {"_id":0, "value":1})
access_token = collection_Authentication.find({"name":"access_token"}, {"_id":0, "value":1})
access_secret = collection_Authentication.find({"name":"access_secret"}, {"_id":0, "value":1})
```

Comment: Use [`.find_one()`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one) and access the key of the dict returned. i.e `consumer_key = collection_Authentication.find_one({"name":"consumer_key"}, {"_id":0, "value":1})["value"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
consumer_key = collection_Authentication.find_one({"name":"consumer_key"})["value"]
```

Use `find_one` to get the document immediately. In Python the document is represented as a dict, so retrieve the string by its field name, "value", using brackets: `["value"]`.